# Unable to initialize and fetch array from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, controller

I was trying to initialize and fetch the array values from the controller.

The [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/28z3v1yx/).

```js
var app = angular.module('carApp', []);

app.controller('carAppCtrlr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.vehicles = [{
        type: 'car',
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        type: 'bike',
        color: 'black'
    }];
};);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app='carApp' data-ng-controller='carAppCtrlr'>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat='v in vehicles'>{{v.type +" " + v.color}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## Output

The values are not getting printed:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete semicolon in last line of your controller definition

```
var app = angular.module('carApp', []);

app.controller('carAppCtrlr', function ($scope) {
   $scope.vehicles = [{
    type: 'car',
    color: 'red'
    }, {
    type: 'bike',
    color: 'black'
   }];
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashot - so quick and prefect! Just updated the fiddle.